# Trouble linking opencv libraries

Tags: c, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm just getting started with OpenCV. I have a Raspberry Pi, and the Pi camera, and I want to learn OpenCV to use in a machine vision project. I'm writing the code in C, edited using vi, on the Raspberry Pi. I'm somewhat new to Linux, and definitely new to writing code in a text editor and not an IDE!

I was able to download the OpenCV repo from Github and compile it without to much trouble. OpenCV (3.2.0) is installed.

I started by following the tutorial here:  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage

I entered the code correctly, and then made the CMake file.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCCV_LIBS} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/lib")
```

I tried making the project but it seems there is a library linking error. I'm a novice and am having trouble ascertaining if it is a version conflict, libraries missing, or just the linker is looking for libraries in the wrong place.

Here is the output when the make command is made:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programming $ cmake .
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.2.0") found components:            core imgproc highgui 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/Programming
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programming $ make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `main':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to   `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x50):  undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14):  undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function  `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
DisplayImage.cpp:  (.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x30): undefined  reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x3c): undefined  reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x140):  undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x68): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'DisplayImage' failed
make[2]: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target  'CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programming $
```

What next? What is the process for troubleshooting linking errors in Linux?/OpenCV 
Any insights you can provide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

- You have mistyped `OpenCVV_LIBS` in your `CMakeLists.txt`
- I think you also need `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})`
- I think *out-of-source* builds are preferred, which means you create a subdirectory called `build` not under version control but in the directory containing `CMakeLists.txt`, `cd build` and then `cmake ..`

Comment: Ok I corrected the OpenCV_LIBS in the CMakeLists.txt file, and made the build directory as you suggested. For the include_directories, do I literally enter "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR", or is that meant to signify the path to an OpenCV directory? I guess I'm not sure how Path variables work in Linux/OpenCV. Thank you for all your help!